# Hide directory name in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, xampp

I have been trying to hide a folder name from a URL and I'm failing miserably. My URL id `0.0.0.0/project/api/api/foo`. As you can see there are two `api`'s and I only want to show one. The `.htaccess` I have been working with resides on the root of the directory and looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/api/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried a couple different variations of this but nothing is working. The first `api` is a directory name and the second `api` is something Laravel puts in for a route and is not a directory. It's ugly to have both, so how can I remove the first `api`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mess with the .htaccess. You just need to update your routes file to not include the second `api` path.

You can either remove the leading `api` segment you've manually defined on your routes, or you can remove the automated `api` prefix that Laravel adds by default to all routes in the `routes/api.php` file.

To remove the default prefix, open your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file, go to the `mapApiRoutes()` method at the bottom, and remove the `'prefix' => 'api',` line.

Comment: That was it! I was going down the WROOOONG path. Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

To make the server accept your requests you can use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^project/api/(.*)$ /project/api/api/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> This rule will make every request to `YOURDOMAIN/project/api/SOMETHING` looks (in your server) as if the actual request was `YOURDOMAIN/project/api/api/SOMETHING`

However - node that you need to make sure that the links **inside** your website/application are correct.

Comment: First, thank you! I tried your suggestion and I still see `0.0.0.0/project/api/api/foo`. I double checked all the links and they are correct.  I'm not sure if it matters, but this is for Laravel which allows me to server up Restfull end-point which is why you see `foo` at the end.

Comment: What do you mean "see"? As in my answer - this change **will not** change your links. It only tells the server how to handle the links.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should of read more closely. As I mentioned in the title of this post, I'm looking to hide the api directory name in my url.

Comment: So just don't put it in the URL :)

Comment: It exists in the URL because you put it there. If you will not put it there - it will not be there.

Comment: I should of been more clear, I apologize. I implemented your suggestion and tried to access `0.0.0.0/project/api/foo` and it did not work. The only way it works is if I use  `0.0.0.0/project/api/api/foo`.

Comment: Check the update (it should be `^project/` [and not `^/project/`]) :)

Comment: Still no luck, I think I may have to rethink this. I'm not sure if this can work with Laravel's routing system.

Comment: Well, I just check this using apache and it works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I do appreciate your help. I'll recheck everything and see if I have something messed up and try again.

Comment: I"ll be sure to accept/vote once I get to the root of the issue. Quick question, the `.htaccess` file should reside on the root of my project directory correct?

Comment: Can be in the root and can be in any of the other sub-directories.